# Error: App Service is configured to not use basic authentication. This requires Web Deploy msdeploy.exe version 7.1.7225 or higher

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have created the .NET 8 Web App in the Azure Portal and deploying the code from the VS 2022 Community version through Azure DevOps Pipelines.

Note:

1. .NET 8 App Service is created on Free Tier Pricing plan
2. Turned the Option `Basic Web App Authentication` to `Off` in `Azure App Service > Configuration > General settings`

Build is successful. But during release pipeline, I'm getting below error:

```
##[error]Error: App Service is configured to not use basic authentication.
This requires Web Deploy msdeploy.exe version 7.1.7225 or higher.
You need a version of Visual Studio that includes an updated version of msdeploy.exe.
For more information, visit https://aka.ms/azdo-webapp-msdeploy
```

[image]

Comment: > Refer my SO answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106188/how-to-not-use-basic-auth-in-a-azure-devops-deploy

Comment: And refer this troubleshooting step as this is a known error -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines#i-cant-web-deploy-to-my-azure-app-service-using-microsoft-entra-id-authentication-from-my-windows-agent

Comment: @SiddheshDesai, you answer also helpful. But the context is different here - not related to Service Connection/Principal, access policies. Kudos to your contribution and efforts. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when disabling Basic Web App Authentication in Azure Web App.

[image]

To solve this issue, we need to use higher version of the msdeploy.exe to deploy the package to Azure Web App.

If you are using Microsoft hosted agents, we can change to use **windows-2019** to **windows-2022** (or windows-latest).

When I changed to use windows-2022 Microsoft-Hosted agent, it will work as expected.

[image]

If you are using self-hosted agents, we can install/upgrade higher version of Visual Studio 2022 on the agent to get a newer version of msdeploy.exe. For example: VS2022 version: **17.8.34330.188**

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc:  [I can't Web Deploy to my Azure App Service using Microsoft Entra ID authentication from my Windows agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines#i-cant-web-deploy-to-my-azure-app-service-using-microsoft-entra-id-authentication-from-my-windows-agent)

Comment: @HarikaReddy Glad to know that the answer can give you help : )

Comment: I tried using windows-2022 or windows-latest but I'm still getting an error. any other issues affecting this?

Comment: Nevermind, I find it on my release pipeline, for some reason the release pipeline uses 2019.