# Error: Deployment of msBuild generated package is not supported. Change package format or use Azure App Service Deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Continue to my previous Question-[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823913/22054564),

I tried changing the ***Agent Specification*** to ***windows-latest*** and also step/task in the release pipeline from **Deploy Azure App service** to **Azure Web App Deploy**:

[image]

**Received this error**:

```
##[error]Error: Deployment of msBuild generated package is not supported. 
Change package format or use Azure App Service Deploy task. 
D:\a\r1\a\_DotNet8WebApp\drop\WebApp.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Error: Publish using zip deploy option is not supported for msBuild package type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines#error-publish-using-zip-deploy-option-is-not-supported-for-msbuild-package-type)

> Web packages created via the MSBuild task (with default arguments) have a nested folder structure that can be deployed correctly only by Web Deploy. The publish-to-zip deployment option can't be used to deploy those packages.

When we use the **Azure Web App deploy** task, it only have **Zip deploy** and **Run From Package** option. And **Deploy Azure App service task** contains the **Web Deploy** option.

For example: Azure Web App deploy task

[image]

In this case, it will show the error in your pipeline.

If your WebApp package is created by Visual Studio build task or Msbuild task, you need to modify the pipeline with the following steps:

1.In the Build solution task, change the MSBuild Arguments to `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\WebAppContent":`

[image]

2.Add an Archive task and change the values as follows:

a. Change Root folder or file to archive to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\\WebAppContent`.

b. Clear the **Prepend root folder name to archive paths** check box:

[image]

Then the msbuild output files will be zipped by archive files task and it can be used to Azure Web App deploy task.

Comment: @HarikaReddy Sure. The question shows detailed error and it allows me to test and answer it easily

Comment: As I'm new to Azure DevOps, I'm not sure whether I provided the issue details correctly and clearly until you or someone upvotes the question because I know the value of voting (up/down), acceptance in the Stack Overflow.
And Thanks to you @KevinLu-MSFT for solutions.
Your solution contains in a form like (Why Issue occurred + Solution + Alternate Solutions + References)